# Ember: Using async data in controller

Tags: asynchronous, ember.js

I have an asynchronous call in an Ember controller, `@authSession.currentUser.clients`. The results of this request is then filtered to populate a drop down menu.

```
 filterClientsBy: (term) ->
   filter = new RegExp("^#{term}", 'i')
   @authSession.currentUser.clients.filter (client) ->
     filter.test(client.displayName)
```

The problem is that the filter doesn't work the first time because it doesn't wait for clients to come back from the server. I feel like I'm missing something fundamental about Ember here. It looks like clients is a `ModelArray`. Can I treat this like a promise somehow? Is there a way to bootstrap this data into the controller before rendering my template?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so there is a couple of things you could do here.

Because there is an asynchronous call in there you need to use a promise in order to wait for the clients relationship to come back. (This is assuming you have "async" set on your client relationship in your model)

This leaves you with a couple of options (I did these in javascript and converted them to coffeescript, so it may look a bit strange):

1) return a Promise from "filterClientsBy" like so:

```
filterClientsBy: (term) ->
    self = this
    filter = new RegExp("^" + term, "i")
    new Ember.RSVP.Promise((resolve, reject) ->
      self.authSession.currentUser.clients.then (clients) ->
      filteredList = clients.filter((client) ->
         filter.test client.displayName
      )
      resolve filteredList
      return
    return
)
```

2) You could create a property on your controller called "filteredClients" that you set inside the resolved "clients" promise block above (instead of returning the promise).

```
filterClientsBy: (term) ->
  self = this
  filter = new RegExp("^" + term, "i")
  self.authSession.currentUser.clients.then (clients) ->
    filteredList = clients.filter((client) ->
      filter.test client.displayName
    )
    self.set "filteredClients", filteredList
    return

  return
```